# El código me funciona localmente pero cuando lo subo al hosting no me corre las consultas SQL me larga el error (ARREGLADO)

Tags: php, mysql

Como dice en el titulo tengo el código de la consulta `SQL` que intento correr localmente y me funciona y al subirlo al hosting no me hace el llamado de los elementos de la tabla y me aparece error como que `MI.price` no coincide con el valor.

Acá dejo el funcionamiento del botón que hace el llamado a la base de datos:

```
if (isset($_POST['btnMenuItemID']) && isset($_POST['qty'])) {
    
    $menuItemID = $sqlconnection->real_escape_string($_POST['btnMenuItemID']);
    $quantity = $sqlconnection->real_escape_string($_POST['qty']);

    $menuItemQuery = "SELECT mi.itemID,mi.menuItemName,mi.price,m.menuName FROM tbl_menuitem mi LEFT JOIN tbl_menu m ON mi.menuID = m.menuID WHERE itemID = " . $menuItemID;

    if ($menuItemResult = $sqlconnection->query($menuItemQuery)) {
        if ($menuItemResult->num_rows > 0) {
            if ($menuItemRow = $menuItemResult->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                echo "
                <tr>
                    <input type = 'hidden' name = 'itemID[]' value ='".$menuItemRow['itemID']."'/>
                    <td>".$menuItemRow['menuName']." : ".$menuItemRow['menuItemName']."</td>
                    <td>".$menuItemRow['price']."</td>
                    <td><input type = 'number' required='required' min='1' max='50' name = 'itemqty[]' width='10px' class='form-control' value ='".$quantity."'/></td>
                    <td>" . number_format((float)$menuItemRow['price'] * $quantity, 2, '.', '') . "</td>
                    <td><button class='btn btn-danger deleteBtn' type='button' onclick='deleteRow()'><i class='fas fa-times'></i></button></td>
                </tr>
                ";
            }
        }

        else {
            //no data retrieve
            echo "null";
        }
        
    }

}
```

y acá esta el botón en el cual se hace el llamado:

```
if((!isset($_SESSION['uid']) && !isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['user_level'])) ) 
    header("Location: login.php");

if($_SESSION['user_level'] != "staff")
    header("Location: login.php");



if (isset($_POST['sentorder'])) {

    if (isset($_POST['itemID']) && isset($_POST['itemqty'])) {

        $arrItemID = $_POST['itemID'];
        $arrItemQty = $_POST['itemqty'];            

        //check pair of the array have same element number
        if (count($arrItemID) == count($arrItemQty)) {              
            $arrlength = count($arrItemID);

            //add new id
            $currentOrderID = getLastID("orderID","tbl_order") + 1;

            insertOrderQuery($currentOrderID);

            for ($i=0; $i < $arrlength; $i++) { 
                insertOrderDetailQuery($currentOrderID,$arrItemID[$i] ,$arrItemQty[$i]);
            }

            updateTotal($currentOrderID);

            //completed insert current order
            header("Location: index.php");
            exit();
        }

        else {
            echo "xD";
        }
    }   
}
function insertOrderDetailQuery($orderID,$itemID,$quantity) {
    global $sqlconnection;
    $addOrderQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_orderdetail (orderID ,itemID ,quantity) VALUES ('{$orderID}', '{$itemID}' ,{$quantity})";

    if ($sqlconnection->query($addOrderQuery) === TRUE) {
            echo "inserted.";
        } 

    else {
            //handle
            echo "someting wong";
            echo $sqlconnection->error;

    }
}

function insertOrderQuery($orderID) {
    global $sqlconnection;
    $addOrderQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_order (orderID ,status, order_date ) VALUES ('{$orderID}','error' ,CURDATE() )";

    if ($sqlconnection->query($addOrderQuery) === TRUE) {
            echo "inserted.";
        } 

    else {
            //handle
            echo "someting wong";
            /* echo $sqlconnection->error; */
            echo "<script>console.log('$addOrderQuery')</script>";

    }
}
```

Acá dejo la estructura de la tabla de `tbl_menuitem`

```sql
CREATE TABLE `tbl_menuitem` (
  `itemID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `menuID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `menuItemName` text NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Este es el codigo de la funcion updateTotal:

```
function updateTotal($orderID) {
    global $sqlconnection;

    $query = "
        UPDATE tbl_order o
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT SUM(OD.quantity*mi.price) AS total
                FROM tbl_order O
                LEFT JOIN tbl_orderdetail OD
                ON O.orderID = OD.orderID
                LEFT JOIN tbl_menuitem MI
                ON OD.itemID = MI.itemID
                LEFT JOIN tbl_menu M
                ON MI.menuID = M.menuID
                
                WHERE o.orderID = ".$orderID."
        ) x
        SET o.total = x.total
        WHERE o.orderID = ".$orderID."
    ";

    if ($sqlconnection->query($query) === TRUE) {
            echo "updated.";
        } 

    else {
            //handle
            echo "someting wong";
            echo $sqlconnection->error;

    }

}
```

Al momento de llamar a toda la consulta local mentí si hace el llamado pero en el hosting me da este error

> «inserted.inserted.someting wrongUnknown column ‘mi.price’ in ‘field list'»

Si se solicita mas información del código no tengo problema en proporcionarla

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el código donde llamas a `insertOrderQuery`? Por  otro lado, el error te indica que la columna `mi.price` no existe y viendo tu consulta te diría que revises la tabla `tbl_menuitem`

Comment: Ya lo modifique! esta la llamada a *insertOrderQuery* y deje la tabla de tbl_menuitem, si te puede servir de ayuda te puedo dejar el repositorio de donde esta alojado el codigo

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código de la función `updateTotal`? Fuera de eso, te recomendaria guardar en la tabla `tbl_orderdetail ` el precio del item, ya que es un dato que probablemente cambien con el tiempo.

Comment: Versión de MySQL en cada entorno?

Comment: ya subí el código de la función de updateTotal

Comment: @Alfabravo como la versión en cada entorno?

Comment: @NahuelSalinas, se refiere a que versión estas usando en desarrollo (_local_) y en producción (_online_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diría que el problema esta en el método `updateTotal`, mas precisamente cuando obtenes el total:

```
SUM(OD.quantity*mi.price) AS total
```

Cambia `mi.price` por `MI.price`.

---

PD: Se me ocurre que para que puedas encontrar más rápido el error podes cambiar:

```
echo "someting wong";
```

Por algo como:

```
echo "someting wong at ". __FUNCTION__;
```

#### Referencia

- [PHP > Constants > Magic constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php)

Comment: Cambie el mi.price por MI.price ahora me arroja el error este:
"que no estoy definiendo la condicion que le quiero aplicar a query"
someting wong insertOrderQueryinserted.someting wongUnknown column 'o.orderID' in 'where clause'.

por lo visto esta en la funcion updateTotal en o.orderID

Comment: @NahuelSalinas, si te fijas, en el `SET` y en el `WHERE` solo tenes que cambiar los alias en minúsculas por mayúsculas.

Comment: Bien lo cambie los errores de llamado a la base de datos no aparecen más ahora lo único que me aparece es *OrderQueryinserted.updated* que podría ser?

Comment: @NahuelSalinas, si te sale ese mensaje significa que todo anduvo bien. Si te referís que no hace la redirección al `index.php` es porque estas haciendo esos `echo`, si los sacas no vas a tener más problemas.